# SharePoint - Programmatically set 'add to all content types' to false

Tags: sharepoint-2013

While adding an existing site column to a SharePoint list, we get an option to set if the column need to be added to all content types or not.

I tried to un-check this property and the site column gets added to the library locally (i.e. without being used in any content type).

**Add Columns from Site Columns**

[image: Screen Shot]

**List of columns**

[image: Screen Shot]

How can I achieve it programmatically? Currently I am using below code which always adds the column to the default content type.

I do not want the column to be added to any content type.

```
if (!list.Fields.ContainsField(reportField.ToString()))
{
    list.Fields.Add(reportField);
    list.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use the [AddFieldAsXml][1] method and set the `AddFieldOptions` parameter to `AddToNoContentType`. See example below:

```
list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchemaXml, false, (AddFieldOptions.AddToNoContentType));
list.Update();
```

If building the field Schema XML is not an option, then you could set the content types to read only whilst you add additional fields then set them back after. This will stop all fields being added to the content types by the AddField method that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Method **AddFieldAsXml** makes it possible to *set 'add to all content types' to false*. Option **'AddToNoContentType'** should be added to the method **AddFieldAsXml** as the 3rd parameter.

PowerShell script example:

```
$ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force))

$fieldSchemaXml="<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='Name' Required='False' MaxLength='255' StaticName='Name' Name='Name' />"

#Add Column to the List
$List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldSchemaXml, $False, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddToNoContentType)
$List.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

More detailed information about method **AddFieldAsXml** can be found in the documentation at the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.addfieldasxml?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server.

More detailed information about all **AddFieldOptions** can be found in the documentation at the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spaddfieldoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server.